# Can I Safely Use Serial1 of ESP32 with GPIOMATRIX?

Tags: uart, serial, gpio, esp32, flash-memories

I am trying to use ESP32 with a Lora module and HMI display in a same project. So I need 2 UARTS. I have connected Lora module ([e32 900t20d](https://urun.n11.com/arduino-urunleri-ve-setleri/yeni-868-mhz-915mhz-5km-menzilli-20dbm-100mw-e32-900t20d-lora-P485945526)) to RX2 (GPIO16), TX2 (GPIO17). Also I want to connect my HMI display to RX1 (GPIO9), TX1 (GPIO10). But there are 2 main problems.

1. My ESP32 board doesn'yt have RX1 and TX1 pins ([30 pins ESP32](https://www.roboshop.com.tr/esp32-wroom-modulu))
2. GPIO 9 and 10 are said flash memory pins, NOT recommended to use

But I watched videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwShqW39jlE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sXtVuMhuoc) about ESP32 hardware serial. They are showing a technic which is **GPIOMATRIX**

```
Serial1.begin (115200, SERIAL_8N1, 4, 2) //Also you can recommend another pins
```

With this technic can I *safely* use Serial1 without crash flash memory or any other?

At this point, it turns out that I do not understand the logic of ESP32. Does ESP32's Flash memory use pins 9 and 10 or does it use RX1 and TX1? So if I change these pins with the matrix method, will the pins of the flash memory also change? If so, it could be a problem.

At Andreas Spiess videos he says ([at 03:37](https://youtu.be/GwShqW39jlE?t=217))

> but if you update the ESP32 files, ESP will crash again

I think that's a different matter